# Correct terminology: "wellposedness of weak solutions to ... equation"?

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, soft-question, notation, terminology

Correct terminology: "wellposedness of weak solutions to ... equation"?

This is a question concering correct use of mathematical terms. It it correct to use the title

> "wellposedness of weak solutions to [$\star$] equation"

to mean that we are going to prove that the weak solutions of a certain PDE [$\star$] exist, are unique, and are stable in some sense?

Or should I rather say

> "wellposedness of [$\star$] equation in the weak sense"

or put it in some other way?